# Ajax call not working in wordpress through a plugin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I have 2 Ajax call the first is working but when it send the data to other the file `send_data.php` and **when I try to run any wordpress function it doesn't work!**

This's the first ajax call ok now the data sent to `send_data.php` file when I try to run any wordpress function like this     `add_post_meta(2, 'dropbox', 'Senddataphp',  false);` it prints this error what I want to do is pretty simple just get the data from ajax insert into wp database but I've no idea everytime I work with js with php problems like this happens

```
caught Error: Call to undefined function add_post_meta() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Dropboxapi\includes\send_data.php:17
        Stack trace:
```

First Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        
                type: "POST",
                url: 'wp-content/plugins/Dropboxapi/includes/send_data.php',
                data: {
                    req: JSON.stringify(dropbox_links)
                },
        
                cache: false,
                success: function(responseData) {
                    // consider using console.log for these kind of things.
                    console.log("Data recived: " + responseData);
                    console.log("First Ajax" + dropbox_links);
        
        
        
                }
            });
```

Second Ajax code here I tried to execute a function that take the sent data and insert into database but it doesn't work, `dropbox.php` file is the main file of the plugin

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'wp-content/plugins/Dropboxapi/dropbox.php',

            data: {
                functionname: 'printdata2'
            },

            success: function(obj, textstatus) {
                if (!('error' in obj)) {
                    var yourVariable = obj.result;
                    console.log("SEc Ajax" + dropbox_links + yourVariable);

                } else {
                    console.log(obj.error);
                    console.log("SEc1 errr Ajax" + dropbox_links +
                        yourVariable);
                }
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                console.log(
                    " errrnot sure what to ask for here to check issue" +
                    msg);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The file `wp-content/plugins/Dropboxapi/dropbox.php` doesn't include `wp-config.php` or similar file so the wordpress functions won't be available. Try include it. BTW, the error says it's in file `send_data.php`

Comment: Yes exactly, the error in `send_data.php`  but the functions of wordpress which run in `dropbox.php` works properly when I try to to execute in `includes/send_data.php` doesn't recognize, I tried now to require multiple wordpress files also not recognized

`define('ABSPATH', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/shortcodes.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/blocks/shortcode.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/functions.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');`

Comment: I made the second Ajax call because the funtion works in dropbox.php so I tried to call the function through dropbox.php but it doesn't work also.

Comment: After including the wordpress file in `includes/send_data.php` prints erroers to each file  like this `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant &quot;WPINC&quot; in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Dropboxapi\includes\send_data.php(6): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ajax in WordPress the file that stores the function you want to run is not called directly. Instead `admin-ajax.php` is called, and callback function is added in `'action'`.
First create a function and add your `add_meta_box` inside it, then add wp_ajax action hooks like the following. Remember that every function which is going to be called by ajax request must end with [wp_die()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/).

```
function printdata2() {
  add_post_meta(2, 'dropbox', 'Senddataphp',  false);
  wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_printdata2', 'printdata2' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_printdata2', 'printdata2' );
```

Next use [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to pass `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` to javascript.

```
function load_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'your-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-js.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'your-js', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
```

Now in your javascript file call `ajaxurl` in `url` and the callback function name in `action`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
  data: {
    action: 'printdata2'
  },
  success: function(obj, textstatus) {
    // obj goes here...
  },
  error: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

Comment: I uploaded the image of the plugin just to demonstrate the project dir: https://imgur.com/a/GrE5VPa 

`dropbox.php` is the main file. so when I add these  2 functions it gonna be excuted and I want to run them when I send ajax data call `function printdata2() {
  add_post_meta(2, 'dropbox', 'Senddataphp',  false);
  wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_printdata2', 'printdata2' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_printdata2', 'printdata2' );`

Comment: and when I run any wp function in `send_data.php` file it doesn't work.