# admin-ajax.php 400 bad request problem (Wordpress)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post

I want to filter the data I pulled from the table with wordpress by date.

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
     var ajaxscript = 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; //absolute ref for testing
       $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
       });  
       $(function(){  
            $("#from_date").datepicker();  
            $("#to_date").datepicker();  
       });  
       $('#filter').click(function(){  
            var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
            var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
            if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
            {  
                 $.ajax({  
                      method: "POST",
                      url: ajaxscript,
                        dataType: 'json', 
                      data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                      success:function(data)  
                      {  
                           $('#order_table').html(data);  
                      }  
                 });  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 alert("Please Select Date");  
            }  
       });  
  });
```

The value code I want to send is as follows:

```
                      <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-5">  
                 <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />  
            </div>
```

But I keep getting **POST http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)** error.

Comment: Remove `method:` and `dataType:`. And you'll have to pass the callback function using `action:` inside `data:`.

Comment: I removed method and dataType. but how can i handle the rest?

Comment: Check this to get an idea on how to handle the rest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72755290/4457943

Comment: Where is the 'action'?